# Plone imagemaps error with zopyx.tinymceplugins.imgmap

Tags: plone, imagemap, kss

I'm using Plone 4.2. I had the need to manage imagemaps in my application so I installed the following product: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zopyx.tinymceplugins.imgmap. This product uses TinyMCE to edit the images and add links to them.

After installing this product, I noticed that I am now unable to view my TinyMCE controls while editing a content type. Looking at my browser's error console, I notice that all my *.kss cannot be read. This is the error that is displayed for all *.kss files:

```
Error: The stylesheet http://localhost:8082/plone/portal_kss/My%20CMS%20theme/++resource++tinymce.kss/tinymce.kss was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/plain", is not "text/css".
Source File: http://localhost:8082/plone/folder-test/image-maps-test/page-with-imagemap/edit
Line: 0
```

I do not understand why there should be error regarding the MIME type. Anyone has a clue on how to fix this?

Additionally, I get the following:

```
GET http://localhost:8082/plone/portal_javascripts/My%20CMS%20theme/plugins/imgmap/editor_plugin.js 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, which TinyMCE version are you using?

Comment: Products.TinyMCE 1.2.12 . I think the main reason is the editor_plugin.js that is not being loaded.

Comment: The paths to the resources are irritating. After the sitename it should immediately continue with '++resource++' but you got 'My%20CMS%20theme' etc. also in the paths. Did you do any resource-registering by yourself?

Comment: Are you experiencing the same error in a page without an imagemap inserted? (To exclude this as an possible error-source). On a vanilla Plone-4.2.1-site with zopyx.tinymceplugins.imgmap installed, everything works fine...

Comment: On a vanilla Plone, everything works OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer my own question:

I opened the product's skins.xml file

(i.e. zopyx.tinymceplugins.imgmap-0.3.1/zopyx/tinymceplugins/imgmap/profiles/default/skins.xml)

This is how it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_skins" allow_any="False" cookie_persistence="False">

 <object name="zopyx_tinymceplugins_imgmap"
    meta_type="Filesystem Directory View"
    directory="zopyx.tinymceplugins.imgmap:skins/zopyx_tinymceplugins_imgmap"/>

 <skin-path name="Plone Default">
  <layer name="zopyx_tinymceplugins_imgmap"
     insert-after="custom"/>
 </skin-path>

 <skin-path name="Sunburst Theme">
  <layer name="zopyx_tinymceplugins_imgmap"
     insert-after="custom"/>
 </skin-path>

</object>
```

It appears that the product has been geared towards specific themes.

Now, my application has a custom theme i.e. MyCustomTheme. When I inspect my portal_skins

**Site > Zope Management Interface > portal_skins > properties**

I notice that indeed the "Sunburst Theme" has included the `zopyx_tinymceplugins_imgmap` skin layer in the 'Plone Default' and 'Sunburst Theme', but NOT in my 'MyCustomTheme'. It has added it right after the `custom` layer.

So I go ahead and manually add `zopyx_tinymceplugins_imgmap` in MyCustomTheme, just immediately after the `custom` layer.

This manages to fix it, and I can now view my TinyMCE controls. I believe there must be a better way to have it work.

Hope this helps someone in future.

**UPDATE:** See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227481/overriding-skins-xml-of-another-product) for a better solution.