# Plone - Overriding skins.xml of another product

Tags: plone, zope

In using Plone, I had the need to use image maps. So I added [this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zopyx.tinymceplugins.imgmap) product to my build. However, I noted that I was not able to use the product in my application. After investigation, I noticed that this particular product had specified specific themes to be used i.e. the plone default themes.

Here is the skins.xml from the product:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_skins" allow_any="False" cookie_persistence="False">

 <object name="zopyx_tinymceplugins_imgmap"
    meta_type="Filesystem Directory View"
    directory="zopyx.tinymceplugins.imgmap:skins/zopyx_tinymceplugins_imgmap"/>

 <skin-path name="Plone Default">
  <layer name="zopyx_tinymceplugins_imgmap"
     insert-after="custom"/>
 </skin-path>
 <skin-path name="Sunburst Theme">
  <layer name="zopyx_tinymceplugins_imgmap"
     insert-after="custom"/>
 </skin-path>

</object>
```

Now my application has a specific theme i.e. MyCustomTheme. When I activate it, I am unable to use the features of the addon product, but when I revert to the Plone default theme, it works OK. This I deduce is from the hardcoding of the themes within that particular product.

How can I fix this to ensure that MyCustomTheme will always be able to use the product? I am thinking of editing my skins.xml file and include the product as a dependency.

**UPDATE:** The authors of the product have finally fixed the bug. The latest version of the product from 0.3.2 should now work OK for all skins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the same layer (`zopyx_tinymceplugins_imgmap`) to your own theme too; it is not dependent on the Default skin, but the author forgot to add a wild-card definition to register the layer with *all* skins.

If you already have a `skins.xml` file for your own theme, simply add the same layer definition to it:

```xml
 <skin-path name="Your Theme Name">
  <layer name="zopyx_tinymceplugins_imgmap"
     insert-after="custom"/>
  <!-- your other skin layer definitions -->
 </skin-path>
```

Make sure you add this product's generic setup profile to your own profile's `medadata.xml` dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>profile-zopyx.tinymceplugins.imgmap:default</dependency>
    <!-- any other dependencies -->

</dependencies>
```

and run your setup profile again.

Comment: Thanks. DO I have to include it in my setup.py file also in install_requires ?

Comment: Well, if your site depends on that package, then that'd be a good idea anyway. :-)

Comment: just released 0.3.2 that registers the layer for every skin path

Comment: Thanks. That will be most appreciated.

Comment: @fRiSi You may want to check on 0.3.2 again. You excluded the docs folder, which is being referenced in setup.py file. Cannot instal it.